# Solving $\int_{[-a,a]}(4t^2+9t^4)^{1/2}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I would like to solve this integral: ($a>0$)

$$\int_{-a}^a\sqrt{4t^2+9t^4}dt,$$ but I do not see how to do this.

I guess it can be done by using the substitution formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Assuming $a\ge0,$

$$\int_{-a}^a\sqrt{4t^2+9t^4}dt=\int_{-a}^a\sqrt{4+9t^2}|t|\ dt$$

$$=\int_{-a}^0\sqrt{4+9t^2}(-t)\ dt+\int_0^at\sqrt{4+9t^2}\ dt$$

Choose $4+9t^2=u$

Comment: The function is even, so you could also just slap a $2$ in front and have the integral from $0$ to $a$...

Comment: Why do you need the assumption $a \geq 0$?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, As we need to resolve $|t|$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int _{ -a }^{ a } \sqrt { 4t^{ 2 }+9t^{ 4 } } dt=\int _{ -a }^{ a } \sqrt { 4+9t^{ 2 } } \left| t \right| dt=-\int _{ -a }^{ 0 } \sqrt { 4+9t^{ 2 } } tdt+\int _{ 0 }^{ a } \sqrt { 4+9t^{ 2 } } tdt=\\ =-\frac { 1 }{ 18 } \int _{ -a }^{ 0 } \sqrt { 4+9t^{ 2 } } d\left( 4+9t^{ 2 } \right) +\frac { 1 }{ 18 } \int _{ -a }^{ 0 } \sqrt { 4+9t^{ 2 } } d\left( 4+9t^{ 2 } \right) =\\ =-\frac { 1 }{ 18 } \int _{ -a }^{ 0 }{ 4+9t^{ 2 } } ^{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }d\left( 4+9t^{ 2 } \right) +\frac { 1 }{ 18 } \int _{ -a }^{ 0 }{ 4+9t^{ 2 } } ^{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }d\left( 4+9t^{ 2 } \right) =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 18 } \left( { -\frac { 2 }{ 3 } \sqrt { { \left( 4+9t^{ 2 } \right)  }^{ 3 } }  }_{ -a }^{ 0 }+{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 } \sqrt { { \left( 4+9t^{ 2 } \right)  }^{ 3 } }  }_{ 0 }^{ a } \right) =\frac { 1 }{ 18 } \left( -\frac { 32 }{ 3 } +\frac { 4 }{ 3 } \sqrt { { \left( 4+9a^{ 2 } \right)  }^{ 3 } }  \right) =\\\ =\frac { 16 }{ 27 } +\frac { 2 }{ 27 } \sqrt { { \left( 4+9a^{ 2 } \right)  }^{ 3 } } $$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(4t^2+9t^4\right)^{1/2}=2t\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{3t}2\right)^2}=\frac49\frac{d}{dt}\left[\left(\frac{3t}2\right)^2\right]\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{3t}2\right)^2}\implies$$

$$\int_{-a}^a\sqrt{4t^2+9t^4}\,dt=\frac49\int_{-a}^a\;\frac{9t}2\,\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{3t}2\right)^2}\,dt=\left.\frac49\frac23\left(1+\left(\frac{3t}2\right)^2\right)^{3/2}\right|_{-a}^a=\ldots$$